# In Telegram Bot API, Update object, can update_id be ever repeated?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In Update object, can `update_id` be ever repeated?

For instance, citing documentation...

> If there are no new updates for at least a week, then identifier of the next update will be chosen randomly instead of sequentially.

Does this mean that after a break of at least one week long, there is a chance to get an Update with `update_id` value that was used in the past for another update?

**UPD.** Citing Telegram Support response:

> As update id should fit in 2^32-1 it’s not technically possible to make it unique (which is obvious) and dev told us that you should rely on sequential order only right when get update to order them by time. Other uses are not recommended and uniqueness of update id also :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can `update_id` be ever repeated?

#### No, an `update_id` is unique!

From the docs, quoting the line before the quote in your question:

> **The update's unique identifier**. Update identifiers start from a certain positive number and increase sequentially. This ID becomes especially handy if you're using [Webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook), since it allows you to ignore repeated updates or to restore the correct update sequence, should they get out of order. **If there are no new updates for at least a week, then identifier of the next update will be chosen randomly instead of sequentially**.
> <sub>[Source](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)</sub>

---

<sub>The `update_id` *has* to be unique, otherwise it will be possible to call `getUpdates` with an already used key, that will then make Telegram think the messages after that id haven't already been seen.</sub>

Comment: "The update's unique identifier" and "the next update will be chosen randomly" contradict each other in some sense. That's what got me confused.

Comment: Wearing the Telegram developers' shoes, I think the logic might have be as following: 1) non-consumed updates do expire in 24 hours; 2) after 7 days (7x the expiration time!) it is safe to choose a random number and start increasing it; 3) on the very first API request after a 7-days break, the API handler just ignores the "offset"; as a result, the API caller will update its "offset" to the biggest one received and procesed.